# CNContactPickerController within a Container View

Tags: swift, uicontainerview, cncontactviewcontroller

I'm fairly new to Swift, so I'm not sure if I'm just not researching the correct terms, but I'm struggling with the CNContactPickerViewController().

Currently, I have the controller creating a new screen (I understand *why* it does this). When I select contacts and hit 'Done', I am able to pull those specific contacts from the list (first name, last name, and phone number) successfully. I'm using the following code to show the controller:

```
let cnPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
cnPicker.delegate = self
self.present(cnPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have a container view set up in XCode under the following variable name:

```
@IBOutlet weak var contactsSubView: UIView!
```

I would like to put the contacts controller *inside the container view* so that it appears within the existing controller. This container view has the following constraints within the view:

```
height: 376
width: 343
Contacts Sub View.top = label + 23
Contacts Sub View.centerX = Safe Area.centerX
```

Comment: The `CNContactPickerViewController` class with their UI, provided by the system. You should not change that, even you can’t.

Comment: I understand I'm not supposed to change the picker itself - that's not what I'm asking. I'm just asking how to put it into a container view so it appears as a piece of the screen.

Comment: I think I'm facing the same problem, but from a slightly different perspective. I had noticed that if you use a no-delegate implementation, you get a default behavior of: single-contact picker is displayed, tapping a contact in the list causes a nav-style segue to the selection in `CNContactViewController (for:)`. I'm trying reverse engineer this via the single-contact delegate, but I can't get the contact display's VC to appear successfully.